# Magento 2.0 - Display custom attribute on product listing page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-catalog

Default **catalog_product_prices.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```

My **catalog_product_prices.xml** to display attribute below product price and above `Add to Cart` button.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
            <block class="Reward\Points\Block\Points" name="reward_points" template="points.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Reward\Points\Block\Points**

```
<?php
namespace Reward\Points\Block;

class Points extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

I tried with above code, but its not working. How do I display custom attribute value in product listing page ?

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to call, In your **list.phtml** file after price code add below code,

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getMyattr(), 'myattr') ?>
```

Make sure from attribute option it is visible for product listing page from admin.

[image]

Comment: what is `getMyattr()`?

Comment: It is attribute code that i had created from admin using attribute creation page. my attribute code was myattr so when i wanted to call it i used, $_product->getMyattr() .

Answer (score 2):

Make sure “Visible on Product View Page on Front-end” and “Used in Product Listing” options under storefront Properties are set to Yes.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked if the "use in product listing" property of the attribute is set to 'yes'? Further, try reindexing if required.

Answer (score 1):

In product list page you can display like this.

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()
   ->getAttribute('attribute identifier');
 if ($attribute) {
        $brick_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()
            ->getValue($_product);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('identifier'); 
if ($attribute) 
{ 
    $attr_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure “Visible on Product View Page on Front-end” and “Used in Product Listing” options under storefront Properties are set to Yes.

This is the most simple way that I have found.

In your **list.phtml** between the foreach function, paste this code.

```
$_getMyAttr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');

// Get Value
$attrTestValue = $_getMyAttr->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

// Get Label
$attrTestLabel = $_getMyAttr->getStoreLabel();
```

**Reference:** https://rafaelstz.github.io/magento/magento2-display-custom-attribute-catalog-list-products.html

Answer (score 0):

using the helper as per one of the answers above is the recommended way:

1. the helper is already used in the code code; therefore you follow the lead from the core team this way (meaning if the core team adds something in this function, your code is benefiting from it right away)
2. without using helper, you will have code that is potentially not secure: looking at the helper function you can see it escapes the data that are parts of the rendering

in short:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getCustomAttribute(), 'custom_attribute') ?>
```